# Como Insertar el punto automáticamente en un EditText en Android

Tags: android

Estoy usando este código para que solo acepte direcciones direcciones IP en el EditText, pero me gustaría que si ingreso mas de tres dígitos automáticamente inserte el punto, alguien me podria decir como hacer esto?

```
InputFilter[] filters = new InputFilter[1];
    filters[0] = new InputFilter() {
        @Override
        public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end,android.text.Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) {
            if (end > start) {
                String destTxt = dest.toString();
                String resultingTxt = destTxt.substring( 0, dstart ) + source.subSequence( start, end ) + destTxt.substring( dend );
                if (!resultingTxt.matches( "^\\d{1,3}(\\.(\\d{1,3}(\\.(\\d{1,3}(\\.(\\d{1,3})?)?)?)?)?)?" )) {
                    return "";
                } else {
                    String[] splits = resultingTxt.split( "\\." );
                    for (int i = 0; i < splits.length; i++) {
                        if (Integer.valueOf( splits[i] ) > 255) {
                            return "";
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
    };
    ipAddress.setFilters( filters );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La opción para que tu `EditText` acepte entradas tipo dirección IP es precisamente como lo estas realizando, mediante un `InputFilter`.

Debe aceptar hasta 3 dígitos para cada segmento y el punto.

ejemplo:

```
    EditText editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);

    //Create InputFilter
    InputFilter[] filters = new InputFilter[1];
    filters[0] = new InputFilter() {
        @Override
        public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end,
                                   android.text.Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) {
            if (end > start) {
                String destText = dest.toString();
                String resultingText = destText.substring(0, dstart) + source.subSequence(start, end) + destText.substring(dend);
                if (!resultingText.matches("^\\d{1,3}(\\.(\\d{1,3}(\\.(\\d{1,3}(\\.(\\d{1,3})?)?)?)?)?)?")) {
                    return "";
                } else {
                    String[] splits = resultingText.split("\\.");
                    for (int i = 0; i < splits.length; i++) {
                        if (Integer.valueOf(splits[i]) > 255) {
                            return "";
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
    };

    //Apply filter!
    editText.setFilters(filters);
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Lo que yo necesito es que si después de introducir 3 dígitos consecutivos y introdusco un cuarto automáticamente se inserta el punto, esto sería solo valido para los 3 primeros segmentos, para el 4to ya no se aplicaría